# $scope variable constantly changing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-material

I have the problem that my variable `$scope.test` is continuously changing.

First I have a function on my node.js server, which returns a json object like the one below:

```
{
    objectOne: "some text",
    objectTwo: "more text",
    objectThree: {
        text: "important text",
        inf: "some info"
    },
    objectFour: "even more text"
}
```

then in angular i have a controller. (This controller is used for 2 html templates. *not sure if important*). So to the function in the controller:

```
$scope.start = function () {
    $location.path('/start');
    SomeService.start({}, someVar, function (success, msg, t) {
        if (!success) {
            console.error(msg);
        }

        $scope.test = t;
        console.log($scope.test); //this prints out the json object above
    });
};
```

And then I have a template file test.html:

```
<div>
    <md-card>
        <md-card-title>
            <md-card-title-text>
                <span class="md-headline">{{test.objectThree.text}}</span>
            </md-card-title-text>
        </md-card-title>
        <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
            <md-button>Cancel</md-button>
        </md-card-actions>
    </md-card>
</div>
```

The problem is that it doesn't display the text. So I made another function in the controller which logs the `$scope.test` every 100ms.

```
$interval(function () {
    console.log($scope.test);
}, 100);
```

The strange thing now is that it prints out like the following example:

```
Object {
        objectOne: "some text",
        objectTwo: "more text",
        objectThree: {
            text: "important text",
            inf: "some info"
        },
        objectFour: "even more text"
       }
```

--

```
undefined
```

--

```
undefined
```

And this continues. once it prints out the object, then 2 times undefined.
BUT when I define a vairable `$scope.test2 = "test2text"` OUTSIDE of the function and then have my html like this:

```
<div>
    <md-card>
        <md-card-title>
            <md-card-title-text>
                <span class="md-headline">{{test2}}</span>
            </md-card-title-text>
        </md-card-title>
        <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
            <md-button>Cancel</md-button>
        </md-card-actions>
    </md-card>
</div>
```

it works and displays the text on the site but I don't have any idea why.

So does anyone has an idea why it is like that?
If you need additional information just ask.
Thank you for taking the time ;)

Comment: `console.log(var);` put this on the $interval and check the result is same. if it is then use if condition to check the value is undefined or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass the `$scope` around, it is something really tricky and can be confusing.

You can however use a `service` to provide `functions` to your controller and use it from there.

See [similar problem and workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24332262/accessing-scope-properties-from-inside-a-service-in-angularjs).

Comment: ok well that was stupid of me to take the name var for example but I actually have another variable name

Comment: well that's a good point, but I solved the problem with another way. I created a second controller for the 2 different HTML files. Because the problem was when changing $location.path it started a new instance of the controller or something similar but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct, because the "similar problem and workaround" was very helpful. But your first sentence isn't quite correct, because I think it started a second instance of the controller and that's why it wasn't displayed in the other html and when logging it the code from 2 instances got executed. But thank you very much.